# How to make a confirm box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show a confirmation box from c# code rather than JavaScript. 
Is there any way I can have the confirmation box pop up when the below condition is true?

Here is the code so far:

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.nav_tree_items, typeof(string), "Alert", "alert('Hello');", true);
}
```

I have already tried add.attributes, but that does not work.

I also tried the following but on click of cancel it performs an action anyway:

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.nav_tree_items, typeof(string), "Confirm", "Confirm('Hello');", true);
}
```

Comment: I have to have conditions, only then it should allow the confirmation box. So I preferred c# would be better than JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.nav_tree_items, typeof(string), "Confirm", "return Confirm('Hello');", true);
}
```

get the return value of the Confirm function in order to cancel or proceed.

**Update 1:**

Or use ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit [Confirm Button](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `confirm` box, but you should take proper action after clicking on `ok/cancel` button.

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
   {
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.nav_tree_items, typeof(string), "Alert", 
      @"var conrimationFlag; conrimationFlag = confirm('Your confirmation 
      message goes here!'); 
      /* now, take proper action here based on the 
      value of variable conrimationFlag */ ", true);
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I said, more action need to put there based on value of `conrimationFlag`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(YourPage), "alert", "<script>alert('Hello')</script>");
}
```

Edit:

in page:

```
<script>
function ConfirmAlert()
{
   var result = confirm('Hello');
   if (result)
   {
      //click ok button
      //do something
   }
   else
   {
      //click cancel button
      //do something
   }
}
</script>
```

code behind

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(YourPage), "ConfirmAlert", "<script>ConfirmAlert()</script>");
}
```

Comment: @user1047883 You can test script using firebug in Firefox. You can see the reasons of error.

Answer (score 0):

look at this example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Do you want to exit...?")
    if (answer){
        alert("Bye bye!")
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
    else{
        alert("Thank you very much Come Again!")
    }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="confirmation()" value="Do you want to leaave">
```

Comment: But I only want to show the above message if a condition is true, if the parent node had child nodes.

Comment: then change the message in the alert("Bye bye") change it to what ever message you want it to show.. replace my example with what you need..

Answer (score 0):

Read about ScriptManager from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx

Try it out,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "KEY", "alert('hello')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
if (items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
{

String _scriptAuthor1 = "javascript:$(function () { " +
                        " return (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?')) });";
nav_tree_items.Attributes.Add("onClick", _scriptAuthor1);
}
```

Comment: This does not ask me for any thing. It just performs the action.

Comment: I changed the "on click" to "OnClientClick"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnClientClick` attribute of `asp:Button`.

Take the sample below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete time this record?');"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of doing it with JavaScript do it with C#!...

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you shure?", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
//do something
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
//do something else
}
```

Comment: For future reference, Messagebox.show() is not usable for ASP.Net websites, because it only works with client-based applications, like Winforms or WPF apps. Only Javascript can show alerts on a webpage.